# How to add/alter a value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a picture that I use with a `Area Map` in html

I have added some bootstrap to the page, but long story short.

I would like to dynamically alter the coordinates of my areas based on the position of the picture after loading.
I get the position of the picture like this

```
var addLEFT = $("#body_hand_foot_image").position().left;
var addTOP = $("#body_hand_foot_image").position().top;
```

So from here I want to add the values of the two variables to the coordinates of the areas. Below is an example of one of those areas.
They are all accurate of the picture is located at x=0 - y=0.

```
<area class="joint" alt="Front Right Neck" href="#" joint="R_Neck_front" full="Right Neck" shape="circle" coords="126,92,8" />
```

Any Ideas?

**Final Solution after some help**

```
function reconfCoords() {
    var items = $('#jointMap').find('area');
    items.each(function () {
        var c = $(this).attr('coords');
        var coords = c.split(',');

        coords[0] = (Number(coords[0]) + Number($("#body_hand_foot_image").position().left)).toString();
        coords[1] = (Number(coords[1]) + Number($("#body_hand_foot_image").position().top)).toString();
        $(this).attr('coords',coords.join());

        var a = $(this).attr('coords');
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to update the ```coords``` attr of ```area``` tag ?

Comment: So, in summary, you want to split the contents of the `coords` attribute, parse the results as integers, add some value to them and serialize them back into the attribute? What are your problems with achieving this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Well, Yes and Yes. and no idea how. But your comment gave me some clues, so I will go try it out.

Comment: Well, maybe approach every step one at a time -- extracting and splitting the values should be easy, as well as parsing strings into integers. You then have to determine how to add the values. I imagine `addLEFT` will be added to the `x` coords and `addTOP` to the `y` coords. The third coord (radius) can be left alone. Then join the values back as strings, which is not difficult either. If you get into trouble, search for information about the specific sub-problem you're solving.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If you are correct about the requirement then, this can achieve by ```var co = $('area').attr('coords').split(','); co[0]+addLeft; co[1]+addRight; $('area').attr('coords', co.join(','))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
var coords = $('area').attr('coords').split(',');

coords[0] = $("#body_hand_foot_image").position().left;
coords[1] = $("#body_hand_foot_image").position().top;

$('area').attr('coords',coords.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $elem.attr() in jQuery to get and set an element attribute. Use Element.getAttribute() and Element.setAttribute() in vanilla HTML.

I assume you want to get the "coords" attribute, split the value on ",", add your values to [0] and [1] respectively, recreate the coord value by rejoining the array, then setting the attribute.